# Failed to load parent route in angular UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my app I have some main modules and each modules has sidebar.
If I click sidebar item then it will route to sidebar linking page but here if I click header again then I am not able to view my parent route page.
I have listed my problem in this [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/rjQ1U3rsFDASvZpHElCW/).
Step to reproduce :

1. By default route1 is selected and dashboard is available on view. Click on Item1.
2. Now click on route1 : Failed to see dashboard view.

```
  <script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
     myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")

      $stateProvider
        .state('route1', {
          url: "/route1",
          templateUrl: "route1.html",
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            $scope.items = ["item1", "item2"];
            $state.go('route1.dashboard');
          }
        })
        .state('route1.dashboard', {
          url: "/dashboard",
          templateUrl: "dashboard.html"
        })
        .state('route1.item1', {
          url: "/item1",
          templateUrl: "item1.html"
        })
        .state('route1.item2', {
          url: "/item2",
          templateUrl: "item2.html"
        })

      .state('route2', {
        url: "/route2",
          templateUrl: "route1.html",
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            $scope.items = ["item3", "item4"];
            $state.go('route2.dashboard');
          }
      })
        .state('route2.dashboard', {
          url: "/dashboard",
          templateUrl: "dashboard.html"
        })
        .state('route2.item3', {
          url: "/item3",
          templateUrl: "item3.html"
        })
        .state('route2.item4', {
          url: "/item4",
          templateUrl: "item4.html"
        })

    })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have in the route1 controller only runs when it's instantiated. Therefore, after you re-visit it from being inside item1, it doesn't need to reload and the $state.go() doesn't fire.

I've forked your plunker with another potential approach: http://plnkr.co/edit/7stMErnkb3rzPJD0Gj5x?p=preview

you should put the dashboard content in the route1 template, rather than attempting to forward to it via $state.go()

so, your route1.html goes from the previous ui-view statement of

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

to

```
  <div ui-view>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
  </div>
```

Now you don't need the dashboard partial, and it loads every time. The item1/item2 partials will replace the content in the ui-view whenever those states activate.

Note in the updated Plunker how Route1 works as you want, while Route2 still doesn't work (as it still has the previous $state.go() approach).